# The zoom sdk for video conferencing integrated properly but the top layout which contains camera, audio button is missing

Tags: android, video-conferencing, zoom-sdk

I have downloaded the sample app from here “https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-android” and and I am referring “example2: An Android app that shows how to join meeting without any login credentials.” its working fine but when I am trying to integrate zoom sdk in another dummy app everything works fine except the layout in the MyMeetingActivity (at the top) which contains Audio,Camera,Share,Participants,More and Leave Buttons is not visible though I am using the exactly same files(MainActivity.java,MyMeetingActivity) from the sample project downloaded from the above git link.

Comment: The best resource for this issue is to head to the Zoom Developers Forum at devforum.zoom.us which is continually monitored by Zoom's API team and other Zoom Developers.

Answer (score 0):

They are always active. If you have any specific problem, you can post their official site(https://marketplace.zoom.us).
**Developer sing up is needed if you developing zoom in your android application.**